# If I ask my company to transfer me from Europe to US, do I need to go through visa lottery?

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration, h1-visa

The company I want to work for has several branches in the world, including Europe and US. I received an offer for a job in Europe (Germany) and I've been told that, after one year, I can ask to be moved to the US.

My question is: would I have to go through a lottery like the H1B lottery?

I read about L-1 visa, but I think that's only for short transfers and does not apply to me, as I want to move to the US permanently, starting with a visa and obtaining a green card after some years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An L1 visa is "dual intent" meaning you can plan, and apply, to stay permanently in the US while working on an L1 visa. Historically, it has been easy to extend for up to five years, but the current administration may make it harder.

Your employer probably knows how this all works, so ask them. "after one year, I can ask to be moved to the US" is consistent with them setting up to petition for an L1 for you.